# How to stop the barcode scanner camera and pass the barcode value to TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, barcode-scanner, flutter-ios, textformfield

I'm using [qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) for IOS app in Flutter, where in the app there is a form containing the product's information: barcode number, name, brand, etc...
and what I did is when the user clicks on the barcode icon on TextFormField its moves to the scanner to scan the barcode. But I'm stuck in the next step where I want to stop the scanner (camera) and then pass the barcode number to the TextFormField like (auto filing) and finally return to the form to complete the product information.

**NOTE: my code is exactly as the example in [qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) so what should I change/add to get the desire result?**

**here is the part of the code**

```
class _scanInoviceState extends State<scanProduct> {
  Barcode? result;
  QRViewController? controller;
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(flex: 4, child: _buildQrView(context)),
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                      if (result != null)
                        Text('${result!.code}') // رقم الباركود من الكاميرا
                      else
                      const Center(
                          child: Text(
                              'قم بمسح الرمز الشريطي للمنتج لإضافته إلى المخزون',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19)))
                  ]))
        ]));
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    setState(() {
      this.controller = controller;
    });
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        result = scanData;
      });
    });
  }

  void _onPermissionSet(BuildContext context, QRViewController ctrl, bool p) {
    log('${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}_onPermissionSet $p');
    if (!p) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('لا يوجد سماح من الكاميرا')));
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of unwanted code in this post. Please try to highlight only the specific problem and post only code related to that so the community can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

In the void _onQrViewCreated you can navigate back to the page with the text input field instead of passing the scannedData to the result.

So you can do

```
controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
   Navigator.of(context).push(
       MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) => /*Widget with your text field*/(
               data: scanData.code,
           ),
       ),
   ); 
});
```

instead of

```
controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
    setState(() {
        result = scanData;
    });
});
```

Comment: What about the barcode number the scanner reads? I have a controller for the TextFormField, can I pass the value (barcode number) to it? and how? this part didn't work with me (data: scanData.code,)

Comment: The barcode number is the data. You have to make a parameter for your widget in which the textfield is. Then data: scanData.code will work. You can do setState(() => controller.text = data);